# Records in input to stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I would like to know if someone can help me sending multiple record to a SQL Server stored procedure.

The scenario is that I have a trigger with a complex logic inside and I would like to move some logic inside a stored procedure.

I try to simplify the scenario with this initial code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.MyTrigger
 ON dbo.MyTable
 AFTER INSERT
 BEGIN

 -- Skipped code

 UPDATE MyField=1 FROM dbo.MyTable2 T INNER JOIN inserted I ON T.Id = I.RefId

 -- Skipped code

 END
```

The desired result is something like this:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER dbo.MyTrigger
 ON dbo.MyTable
 AFTER INSERT
 BEGIN

 -- Skipped code

 exec dbo.MyStoredProcedure inserted;

 -- Skipped code

 END
```

As you can see the UPDATE statement has been replaced with a call to a stored procedure MyStoredProcedure (in real scenario this procedure will do multiple things with those records).
The idea is then to write the stored procedure as below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MyStoredProcedure @inserted ??? AS BEGIN 

UPDATE MyField=1 FROM dbo.MyTable2 T INNER JOIN @inserted I ON T.Id = I.RefId

END
```

Is it possible? Which type should the @inserted parameter be declared? Other ideas?

For perfomance reasons I cannot solve this problem with a cursor and calling the procedure for each inserted record.

Comment: Please don't "quote" your code, use the code formatting option.

Comment: You want a user defined table type.

Comment: What you want is more complex, not simpler. What's the actual purpose of the stored procedure? It matters. `inserted` is a table, not records. You can't pass `inserted` as a parameter. If the stored procedure code is both long *and* meant to be reused, you could write the new rows (or just the IDs) to a temporary table and JOIN with it. You can specify any indexes you need on the temporary table to speed up the rest of the code

Comment: It is possible to do with a user defined table type, but it will complicate your code and can have a nasty effect on performance, so unless you have a very good reason as to *why* do it at all, I recommend against it.

Comment: If you need this, probably easiest is to do: `select * into #inserted from inserted; select * into #updated from updated; exec someCommonProcedure` and let the procedure work with the #inserted/#updated table copies. The upside of this method is that one can actually index these temporary tables. Just watch out for nested triggers which might complicate things for you, because you will already have the #-tables in the scope (maybe)

Comment: An alternative solutionogjr be to have a scheduled task that does the work, and it processes only new/changed rows. Don't forgot that anything you do in the trigger will make your DML statement take *longer*, which impacts performance for both you and your other users. Having to execute a procedure can often not be a performant solution *inside* the trigger.

Comment: @siggemannen Or use a Table Valued Parameter

Comment: @Charlieface yeah, they aren't as flexible though, especially if you want a common procedure to be used for many different tables (ie. for logging).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the recommendations.
I used Dale K solution of user defined table type.

I appreciated the recommendation of Zohar that this option will add some extra work but I appreciated because in my scenario is taking not so much time and help to keep clean the trigger code.

Also Thom recommendation is very important to keep in mind but actually doesn’t affect my scenario while scheduled task cannot by applied.

Thank you to all of you

Comment: The thank you are better suited for comments. For your answer, could you [edit] this to provide more details on the solution you ended up using, and why that solved your problem? It may be useful to cite information from Dale’s original comment.